# Select de 2 tabelas Java

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

Olá pessoal eu estou tendo problemas para trazer dados de 2 tabelas diferente do banco de dados HSQLDB minha classe DAO esta assim:

```
@Override
public List<Animal> listar() throws Exception {
    List<Animal> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        statement = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT a.id,a.nome,a.nascimento,e.nome FROM animal a INNER JOIN especie e ON (a.especie_id = e.id)";
        rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt(1);
            String nome = rs.getString(2);
            Date nascimento = rs.getDate(3);
            String especie = rs.getString(4);
            Animal tempAnimal = new Animal(id,nome,nascimento);
            lista.add(tempAnimal);
            con.close();
        }
        return lista;
    }catch (Exception e){           
        con.close();
    }finally{
        con.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

e minha classe de Modelo Animal esta assim:

```
private Especie especie;
private int id;
private String Nome;
private Date DataDeNascimento;



public Animal() {

}


public Animal(int id, String nome, Date dataDeNascimento, Especie especie) {
    super();
    this.especie = especie;
    this.id = id;
    this.Nome = nome;
    this.DataDeNascimento = dataDeNascimento;
}
```

classe de modelo Especie

```
private Tipo_animal tipoanimal;

private int id;
private String nome;
private String Descricao;
private List<Animal> animais;


public Especie() {


}

public Especie(Tipo_animal tipoanimal, int id, String nome, String descricao, List<Animal> animais) {
    super();
    this.tipoanimal = tipoanimal;
    this.id = id;
    this.nome = nome;
    Descricao = descricao;
    this.animais = animais;
}
```

estrutura do banco de dados:

```
CREATE TABLE ANIMAL
(
ID             BIGINT IDENTITY NOT NULL ,
NOME           VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL ,
NASCIMENTO     DATE ,
ESPECIE_ID BIGINT NOT NULL ,
constraint ANIMAL_PK primary key (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ESPECIE
(
ID                   BIGINT IDENTITY NOT NULL ,
NOME                 VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL ,
DESCRICAO            VARCHAR (100) ,
TIPO_ANIMAL_ACRONIMO CHAR (3) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT ESPECIE_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

ALTER TABLE ESPECIE ADD CONSTRAINT ESPECIE_NOME UNIQUE ( NOME ) ;

ALTER TABLE ANIMAL ADD CONSTRAINT ANIMAL_ESPECIE_FK FOREIGN KEY ( ESPECIE_ID ) REFERENCES ESPECIE ( ID ) ;
```

eu preciso pegar o nome da espécie dos animais e eu não estou conseguindo, eu consigo apenas trazer os dados do animal como o id, nome e a data de nascimento, quando eu coloco a espécie no meu método construtor eu não consigo trazer os dados dele junto com os dados do animal se alguém puder me ajudar ficaria grato.

Comment: Felipe, se possivel, adcione em forma textual, nem todos podem ter acesso as imagens.

Comment: `e.nome` não é o nome da especie? Como está sua classe especie?

Comment: adicionei a classe especie

Comment: Sua classe especie recebe uma lista de animais e Animal recebe especie? Sua modelagem está com sérios problemas.

Comment: tem como eu resolver, para poder dar o select nos animais  e vir o nome da especie?

Comment: Então, nao está dando pra entender bem a logica aplicada, porque especie precisa receber uma lista de animais, sendo que cada animal recebe uma especie?

Comment: vou tentar explicar oq eu preciso fazer, eu tenho 3 tabelas no meu banco tem Animal , Especie e Tipo_animal, cada animal cadastrado no banco tem sua especie ex: totó pertence a especie cachorro, pra eu adicionar
um animal novo no banco eu preciso dizer a qual especie ele pertence se nao eu nao consigo cadastrar. agora eu cadastrei animais no banco via hsqldb e eu preciso puxar eles do banco so que ate agora eu consegui
puxar apenas os dados do animal ex: id nome e nascimento, eu nao consigo puxar a especie a qual ele pertence, sera q eu modelei errado por isso nao esta dando certo?

Comment: Você quer receber um objeto `Especie` no construtor de `Animal`? Se for isso, você vai precisar alterar toda a sua lógica de consulta, uma vez que a única informação de espécie que está sendo retornada é o nome.